# Mongos not starting using YAML format for config file

Tags: mongodb, config

I am trying to start mongos using config file with YAML format. it is throwing error saying "Unrecognized option: sharding.configDB". I am running this on centos6.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Config file:

```
systemLog:  
   destination: file  
   path: REPLACEWITHLOGPATH  
   quiet: true  
processManagement:  
   fork: true  
net:  
   bindIp: REPLACEWITHIP  
   port: REPLACEWITHPORT  
storage:  
   dbPath: REPLACEWITHDBPATH  
sharding:  
   clusterRole: shardsvr  
   configDB: "172.16.4.61:27019"
```

Comment: it will be much easier to help you if you include your config file as part of the question.

Comment: Added config file this time. Place holders will be dynamiacally populated during mongo installation process.

Comment: Kay's answer is correct (in that you should only have `sharding.clusterRole` for a `mongod`, not a `mongos`) .. however `sharding.configDB` should be valid for `mongos`. Are you sure you are getting this error message when trying to start a `mongos` and not a `mongod`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to remove the clusterRole: shardsvr from your mongos configuration file